# Define a default child (reverse ForeignKey)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 models Foo and Bar. Each Foo has multiple Bars, but one needs to be the "default". At this point I have a foreignkey in Bar pointing to Foo, but now I need a way to specify which of the Bar's belonging to Foo is the default. I tried setting another foreignkey in Foo that points to a Bar (with a unique related_name), but I get all sorts of errors (including in the django-admin templates).

Code so far:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    default_bar = models.ForeignKey('Bar')

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

I have absolutely NO problem with a completely new solution as I'm probably doing it wrong anyways. The only other way I can think of is to have a separate table that connects Foos and Bars and having the Foo part unique, but that makes the admin interface a MESS.

Answer (score 0):

If a Foo can have multiple Bars, then can a Bar belong to multiple Foos? If so then you can solve this really easily with a `ManyToManyField` and the `through` parameter, like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, through='FooBar')

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    is_default = models.BooleanField()
```

Check the Django documentation on ["Extra fields on many-to-many relationships"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

And just as a note, posting a simple version of your actual problem (ie. saying `Person` and `Group` vs. `Foo` and `Bar`) helps, as we get a better understanding of what you're actually trying to model! That way it's easier to see where the relationships should actually go.

Comment: No, each Bar can only have 1 Foo. I'm actually using this in a few place on a shopping cart site. One is for options on a product. The default allows the admin to set default options for the product so that users can quickly add products to their shopping cart without having to modify everything. It also lets the admin pre-select optimal configurations to start from (instead of it being random).